# Rails. Migration enum with "t.cloumn..." or "t.integer"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Sometimes in a migration file I see:

```
t.column :model_type, :integer, default: 0, null: false
```

and sometimes:

```
t.integer :model_type, default: 0, null: false
```

for **enum types**.

Which is the correct way?

Comment: This two ways are same

Comment: @IlyaLavrov are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's add columns to a table in both ways:

```
t.column :model_type1, :integer, default: 0, null: false
t.integer :model_type2, default: 0, null: false
```

Now we may check how Rails stores these two columns in `schema.rb`:

```
t.integer "model_type1", default: 0, null: false
t.integer "model_type2", default: 0, null: false
```

Also we may check the table structure in a database (PostgeSQL in my case):

```
model_type1 | integer | not null default 0
model_type2 | integer | not null default 0
```

As you can see, both ways gives the same result.